# Question regarding a problem derived from Evans PDE's book:

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I came across this problems i few months and go and thought i would give it a try. The problem goes as following:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $R^n$, $\alpha>0, f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and we have:

(1) \begin{cases}  -\Delta u_\alpha= f  \ \textrm{ in }\  \Omega \\ \alpha u_\alpha + \frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial \nu}=0 \ \textrm{ on } \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}

(a) Prove that when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ then $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_D$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $u_D$ is a solution of:

(D) \begin{cases}  -\Delta u= f  \ \textrm{ in } \  \Omega \\ u=0 \ \textrm{on} \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}

(b) Prove that when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ then, if $f \perp1$ (which is the same as $\int_\Omega f=0)$ , we have $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_N$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $u_N$ is a solution of:

(N) \begin{cases}  -\Delta u= f  \ \textrm{ in } \  \Omega \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 \ \textrm{ on } \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}.

I left some images of what I managed to do so far, but i don't understand how i'm suppose to show that $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_D$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ or $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_N$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. I tried to prove that $||u_{\alpha}-u_D||^2_{H^1(\Omega)}\rightarrow 0$ when  when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ and $||u_{\alpha}-u_N||^2_{H^1(\Omega)}\rightarrow 0$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ but i can't get to this.

Thanks for your help.

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFeVu.jpg)

[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S3t3.jpg)

[Third page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chbDq.jpg)

Comment: Is $\Delta$ the Laplacian? Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}$ the directional derivative in the direction perpendicular to $\partial \Omega$? Can we assume $\partial \Omega$ is a smooth $(n-1)$-manifold, or at least differentiable?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, yes and we can assume that it's a smooth $(n-1)$-manifold.